# brew path didn't cover sbin

Tags: homebrew, path

I have problem when I used brew to install aircrack-ng. I found out that it cover path

```
/usr/local/Cellar/aircrack-ng/1.1/bin
```

but it couldn't find commands after I tried tab-completion in path

```
/usr/local/Cellar/aircrack-ng/1.1/sbin
```

What should I do? Do I need to add another path?

Comment: Have you tried `brew doctor` already? Does it say something about your PATH?

Answer (score 3):

The `sbin` directory, which some admin tools like dsniff and aircrack install to, is not on the path by default, and it's not in Homebrew's initial setup instructions, which tell you to get `/usr/local/bin` on your path. This is because, traditionally, `sbin/` is for administrative tools that only root would expect to run.

Tab completion is picking up the files in `/usr/local/Cellar/aircrack-ng/1.1/bin` because they are symlinked in to `/usr/local/bin`, which is on your PATH. It does not find the files in `/usr/local/Cellar/aircrack-ng/1.1/sbin`, because they are symlinked in to `/usr/local/sbin`, which is not on your PATH. Your current working directory does not matter for tab-completion, because `.` (the current directory) is not on the PATH.

If you want to see those other programs on your path, where tab-completion can pick them up, add `/usr/local/sbin` to your PATH in the same place you added `/usr/local/bin` - probably your ~/.bashrc file.

In general, if you want to use tab-completion on programs in the current directory, you need to call them with a `./` prefix. For example, `cd /usr/local/sbin` and then type `./air` and hit tab, and you'll get some choices.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, .../bin directories are for all users, .../sbin directories are for usage by root only. I don't know the setup if homebrew, but maybe /usr/local/Cellar/aircrack-ng/1.1/sbin is on the path if you are root?